# Why does my BETWEEN predicate not match any rows?

Tags: mysql

I got this table list:

table `pinjam`

```
kd_pinjam(primary) |  norek        | tgl_pinjam | jml_angsuran | jml_pinjam | sisa 
pin-0001           | 7811088313831 | 2020-12-20 | 10           | 5000000    | 10
```

table `riwayat_pinjam`

```
kd_pinjam(primary) | norek         | jml_pinjam | angsuran | gagal_bayar | tgl_lunas 
pin-0001           | 7811088313831 | 5000000    | 10       | 0           | null
```

I want to create a monthly report, for customers that have loan in a certain month (ex: January)

This is syntax that I use:

```
SELECT sum(pinjam.jml_pinjam) as pinjam 
from pinjam 
left join riwayat_pinjam 
  on pinjam.kd_pinjam = riwayat_pinjam.kd_pinjam 
where month(tgl_pinjam) BETWEEN month('2020-12-01') and month('2021-02-28')
```

But the result I get is that `pinjam` is null. I expect `pinjam` to equal 5000000.

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x BETWEEN a AND b` translates to `x >= a AND x <= b`. In your case `a` is 12 and `b` is 2; there is nothing that is simultaneously greater than 12 and less than 2, so no rows match.

Comment: oh yeah, 
after i edited the values to 2020-01-01, its working

Answer (score 2):

This will avoid most issues:

```
where tgl_pinjam >= '2020-12-01'
  AND tgl_pinjam  < '2020-12-01' + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Even without worrying about leap year.